# How large can a planar triangulation be that embeds bi-Lipschitz in a ball of $\mathbb{R^3}$?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $G$ be a finite plane graph all bounded faces of which are triangles. For example, $G$ could be
 the 1-skeleton of a triangulation of a topological disc. Let $f: V(G) \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a bi-Lipschitz map, i.e.
$$d(x,y) ≤ |f(x)−f(y)| ≤ Cd(x,y) (1)$$
for a fixed $C\geq 1$ and every $x,y\in V(G)$, where $d(x,y)$ denotes the graph distance.

Note that (1) implies an upper bound on the degrees of $G$ (depending on $C$).

Let $diam(G)$ denote the diameter of $G$.
Can $G$ have more than $\Theta(diam(G)^2)$ vertices?
What is the supremal $r$ such that there is a family ${G_i}$ of graphs satisfying (1) and $|V(G_i)| = \omega(diam(G_i)^r)$?

The question can also be stated with the graph G replaced by a Riemann surface, and $|V(G_i)|$ replaced by its area.

Embedding a portion of the triangular lattice `flat’ shows that $r\geq 2$, and $r\leq 3$ is easy by a volume argument. Any bounds in (2,3) would be welcome.